# Using Math Symbols Stored in an Array as a String

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm very new to Ruby and I'm trying to use math symbols that are stored in an array as strings to perform math. This is for a Reverse Polish Notation calculator I'm working on. For example:

```
var = ['1','2','+']
```

I've puzzled through enough regular expressions to figure out how to differentiate numbers from non-numbers in an if statement, but I'm trying to figure out how I could make the following work to produce -1.

```
var[0]  var[2] var[1]   #=>   1 - 2
```

Does anyone know how to change the string '-' back into the math symbol?

Comment: You cannot do it. "Math symbol" is not a Ruby object. In other words, there is no such thing within Ruby code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
'1'.to_i.send('-', '2'.to_i)
# => -1
```

`send` calls the first argument as a method on the object, with the remaining arguments as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is using the `eval` function

```
result = eval "#{var[0]} #{var[2]} #{var[1]}"
```